# Pass variable from bash script to ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash

I have a bash script that executes a ruby script. It passes in 4 variables to the ruby script. However, the ruby script is not accessing these variables but instead using the variable name as if it was the value.

In my bash script I define 4 variables eg

```
var1 = "some string"
var2 = "another string"
var3 = "string 3"
var4 = "string 4"
```

and call the ruby script with

```
ruby ./myScript.rb var1 var2 var3 var4
```

in ruby script I access as ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3]
however, the ruby script does not get "some string" but instead "var1" etc

how can I pass these variables correctly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I needed to pass the variables in as:

```
ruby ./myScript.rb ${var1} ${var2} ${var3} ${var4}
```

using quotations did not work for me

Comment: You need to accept the correct answer instead of posting the same in the first place.